# UISwitch resets when scrolling up and down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a question about the event value changed for UISwitch, here is my problem in detail.

in numberOfRowsInSection i have loop that calls the a data base method which return #of rows for each section.

I used an array of arrays(BECAUSE OF I HAVE MANY SECTIONS WITH MANY ROWS) that keeps state of UISwitch then update it whenever value changed called, here is the code of the event:

HOWEVER, after all of these UISwitch still resets whenever I scroll up or down. PLEASE HELP ME AS SOON AS POSSIBLE I will appreciate YOUR HELP SOOOOO MUCH . 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please avoid all of the uppercase wording and asking for help ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make logic error in `if (sender.on)` in `-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender` method because when `sender.on == YES` you make OFF:) write

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *x =[mainTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSMutableArray *repl = [SwitchArray objectAtIndex:x.section];
    [repl replaceObjectAtIndex:x.row withObject:(sender.on ? @"ON", @"OFF")];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can double check the value in the table view `willDisplayCell:` just to make sure you have it right:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UISwitch* uiSwitch = (UISwitch*) cell.accessoryView;
    if (uiSwitch != nil && [uiSwitch isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) {
        //just make sure it is valid
        NSLog(@"switch value at %d-%d is: %@",indexPath.section, indexPath.row,  [SwitchArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] );
        uiSwitch.on = [[SwitchArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"ON"];
    }

}
```

As an aside, you can you use NSNumbers to make the code more readable:

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *x=[mainTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)x.section);

    //NSLog(@"index for switch : %d", switchController.tag );
     NSMutableArray *repl =  repl= [SwitchArray objectAtIndex:x.section];

   repl[x.section]  = @(sender.on);
}
```

Then where you set the `on` value:

```
 uiSwitch.on = [[SwitchArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused. You are creating a new switch every time a cell is used. You should only create a switch once for each cell. Try the following in your `cellForRow...` method:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UISwitch *switchController = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [switchController setOn:YES animated:NO];

    [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.accessoryView = switchController;
    [switchController release];
}

UISwitch *switch = cell.accessoryView;
```